# How do I get the standard expected Controller-Action-ID from Html Helper ActionLink instead of query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I suspect someone will call this a duplicate....I have looked through the examples that I have seen and tried to implement the suggested changes but I am still having this issue.  In my index view, I have an ActionLink HTML Helper to redirect to an Edit.  When I mouse over it, it shows the URL target as:

`http://localhost:58028/Instruments/Edit?InstrumentId=1`

Instead of the desired

`http://localhost:58028/Instruments/Edit/1`

I have built a "for comparison" scaffolded situation and it appears to me that I am doing the exact same thing, yet it is resulting in the proper URL.  When I debug and stop in the Edit routine of the controller, it shows me that it is using the correct (and only) mapping.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing:

Here's my View code:

```
 <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Edit", new { InstrumentId = item.InstrumentId })</td>
```

Here's my Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? InstrumentId)
```

and here's my routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the Html Helper to this

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Edit", new { id = item.InstrumentId })
```

Comment: This does not work since the parameter is `InstrumentId`, not `id`!

Comment: ohk which part you dont understand?because its working for me given the question

Comment: No it is not (and clearly you have not even tested it). The parameter in OP's method is `int InstrumentId` but your code is just passing a value for a parameter named `id` and not passing any value for `InstrumentId` (so it will be `null`). All you have done is copy the first part of my answer but omitted the other necessary change.

Comment: ohk you see   public ActionResult Edit(int? InstrumentId) this "InstrumentId" is a variable so i can even say  public ActionResult Edit(int? xId)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150150/discussion-between-jephren-naicker-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

Your default route expects a parameter named `id`, so to use the default route, change the link to

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Edit", new { id = item.InstrumentId })
```

and the method to

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
```

or create a specific route for your method that includes a placeholder for a parameter named `InstrumentId` and place it before the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "InstrumentEdit",
    url: "Instruments/Edit/InstrumentId",
    defaults: new { controller = "Instruments", action = "Edit" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    ....
```

Both options will generate `../Instruments/Edit/1`